# Alexa AudioPlayer Request Directive not working

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit, audio-player

I am making an audio player skill, the audio gets played when I test the skill with no error, but AudioPlayer requests such as AudioPlayer.PlaybackStarted, AudioPlayer.PlabackStopped diesctives are not working. I have handled them in my code with below function same as used in example in Github.

https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player/blob/mainline/multiple-streams/lambda/src/index.js

```
const AudioPlayerEventHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
  return 
  handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type.startsWith('AudioPlayer.');
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
  const {
  requestEnvelope,
  attributesManager,
  responseBuilder
} = handlerInput;
const audioPlayerEventName = requestEnvelope.request.type.split('.')[1];
const {
  playbackSetting,
  playbackInfo,
  audioData,
  timeStamp
} = await attributesManager.getPersistentAttributes();

switch (audioPlayerEventName) {
  case 'PlaybackStarted':
    playbackInfo.token = getToken(handlerInput);
    playbackInfo.index = await getIndex(handlerInput);
    playbackInfo.inPlaybackSession = true;
    playbackInfo.hasPreviousPlaybackSession = true;
    break;
  case 'PlaybackFinished':
    playbackInfo.inPlaybackSession = false;
    playbackInfo.hasPreviousPlaybackSession = false;
    playbackInfo.nextStreamEnqueued = false;
    break;
  case 'PlaybackStopped':
    playbackInfo.token = getToken(handlerInput);
    playbackInfo.index = await getIndex(handlerInput);
    playbackInfo.offsetInMilliseconds = getOffsetInMilliseconds(handlerInput);
    break;
  case 'PlaybackNearlyFinished':
    {
      if (playbackInfo.nextStreamEnqueued) {
        break;
      }

      const enqueueIndex = (playbackInfo.index + 1) % audioData.length;

      if (enqueueIndex === 0 && !playbackSetting.loop) {
        break;
      }

      playbackInfo.nextStreamEnqueued = true;

      const enqueueToken = playbackInfo.playOrder[enqueueIndex];
      const playBehavior = 'ENQUEUE';
      const podcast = audioData[playbackInfo.playOrder[enqueueIndex]];
      const expectedPreviousToken = playbackInfo.token;
      const offsetInMilliseconds = 0;

      responseBuilder.addAudioPlayerPlayDirective(
        playBehavior,
        podcast.url,
        enqueueToken,
        offsetInMilliseconds,
        expectedPreviousToken,
      );
      break;
    }
  case 'PlaybackFailed':
    playbackInfo.inPlaybackSession = false;
    console.log('Playback Failed : %j', handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.error);
    return;
  default:
    throw new Error('Should never reach here!');
}

return responseBuilder.speak('directive is sent').getResponse();
```

},
};

Comment: Were you able to fix this?